# MySQL row totals per value

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, pivot

MySQL table structure like this:

```
| id | company_id | project_id | status |
|  1 |          1 |          1 |  draft |
|  2 |          1 |          1 |   done |
|  3 |          1 |          1 |    wip |
|  4 |          1 |          2 |  draft |
```

I would like to run a single query on the table and get results like this for a single company_id:

```
| project_id | draft | wip | done | total |
|          1 |     1 |   1 |    1 |     3 |
|          2 |     1 |   0 |    0 |     1 |
```

Table could have >.5M rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select project_id, 
    sum(status = 'draft') draft,
    sum(status = 'wip') wip,
    sum(status = 'done') done,
    count(*) total
from mytable
group by project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can distinctly select all `status` cases and then pivot dynamically in order to have all `status` values even if newly inserted values other than the current ones :

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT(
                    'SUM( status =''', status, ''' ) AS ',status
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT status
           FROM t 
       ) t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT company_id, project_id,',@sql,',COUNT(*) AS total'
                   ' FROM t
                    GROUP BY company_id, project_id'); 


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1b0fa6c49dfb2278f330609ba95183a9)</kbd>